# How to think of group actions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I am a little confused on how exactly I should be thinking of an action on a group.  I have been trying to read up on it and came across [Timothy Gower's blog](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/11/06/group-actions-i/) which I think does a good job explaining it.  However, as I started my first homework problem it said prove that the additive group Z acts on itself by z$\cdot$a = z + a for all $a, z \in Z$.  My problem comes with the fact Gower's says you can think of an action as a permutation of the set, however for z > 2 you can no longer replicate the set with the action because your set (the image of your action) will start at 1 + z, thus not including 1,2,...,z so how can it be a permutation?  I would appreciate help clearing this up.  Thanks.

Comment: The integers, $\mathbb Z$, contain negative numbers. It's not clear what you mean by "will start at..."

Comment: Yes, I realized I was thinking the group of positive integers.  It makes more sense now.

Comment: Note, the positive integers are not a group, at least under any of the usual operations.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a group $G$ is said to act on a set $X$ if each $g \in G$ can be thought of as a bijection $X \to X$ (and we need that the identity $e \in G$ is the trivial bijection and that these maps satisfy associativity $(gh)(x) = g(h(x))$ for $x \in X$). Any bijection of a set can be thought of as a rearrangement or a permutation of the set $X$, so what this is saying is that each element $g$ of the group $G$ gives us a way to permute all of the elements of $X$.

Let's now consider your example. We are saying that the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ act on themselves as follows: given an element $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, we get the map $x \mapsto x + a$. That is, the group element $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ ''permutes'' the integers by shifting everything by $a$. Said differently, $1$ gets sent to $1+a$, $2$ gets sent to $2+a$, $3$ gets sent to $3+a$, and so on. But every integer gets hit and it only gets hit by one element, so ''adding $a$'' is indeed a bijection of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: ahh ok, for some reason I was thinking positive integers.  To clarify, if it was the group of positive integers under addition, then the group would not act on itself right? Because for the case a = 2, then image of the action \neq codomain of the action, thus not a bijection, correct?

Comment: If the group $G$ consisted only of the positive integers, then we would have a problem: if you're adding $5$ to everything say, then how can you get the elements $1,2,3,4$? That is, the action of an element of $G$ is not a bijection, so this is then not a group action.

Comment: That makes perfect sense thanks! Follow up though, can two elements act the same on the set? In other words can some permutation given by $g_o$ be the same as the permutation given by $g_1$?

Comment: Sure, for example, the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ act on the group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ as follows: given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, send $x \mapsto nx$. Then, the arithmetic progressions $n + p, n+2p, n+3p,\ldots$ are all going to act the same way.